# Pandas Window Average Based On Conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to perform a window operation on the following pandas data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'visitor_id': ['a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c'],
                   'time_on_site' : [3,5,6,4,5,3,7,6,7,8,1,2,2,1,2],
                   'site_visit': [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5],
                   'feature_visit' : [np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,2,3,1,2,3,4,np.nan,1,2,3,np.nan]
                  })
```

> "For each distinct user, calculate the average time they spent on the website and their total number of visits before they interacted with a feature."

The data consists of four columns with the following definitions:

**visitor_id** is a string that identifies a unique given visitor

**time_on_site** is the time they spent on the website

**site_visit** is an incrementing counter of the times they visited the 
website.

**feature_visit** is an incrementing counter of the times they used a specific feature on the site.  If a customer visited the site before they interacted with the feature, a NaN is produced.  If they visited the site and did not interact with the new feature, a NaN is produced. For each time they visited the site and interacted with the feature, the counter is incremented by one.

```
visitor_id time_on_site site_visit feature_visit
a   3   1   NaN
a   5   2   NaN
a   6   3   1
a   4   4   NaN
a   5   5   2
a   3   6   3
b   7   1   1
b   6   2   2
b   7   3   3
b   8   4   4
c   1   1   NaN
c   2   2   1
c   2   3   2
c   1   4   3
c   2   5   NaN
```

The expected output should look like this:

```py
id   mean   count
a    4       2  
b    NaN     0
c    1       1
```

Which was created based on the following logic:

For user `a`, the expected output is 4, which is the average time_on_site for site_visit 1 and 2, which occurred before the first feature interaction on site_visit 3.

For user `b` the average time should be NaN because they had no prior visits before their first interaction with the feature.

For user `c`, their average time is just 1, since they only had one visit before interacting with the new feature.

If a user never used the new feature, their mean and count should be NaN.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def summarize(x):
    index = x[x['feature_visit'].notnull()].index[0]

    return pd.Series({
        'mean': x[x.index < index]['time_on_site'].mean(),
        'count': x[x.index < index]['site_visit'].count()
    })

df.groupby('visitor_id').apply(summarize)
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you!